# Fedora 29: screen blank/flickering after upgrade to Kernel 5.x on DELL XPS 15 9570

Tags: fedora, kernel, boot

I am running Fedora 29 on a DELL XPS 15 9570, latest BIOS installed.

Since upgrading to kernel 5.0.3 / 5.0.5, my laptop screen stays blank (with occasional white flicker) after the BIOS logo, and it makes a weird high-frequency, "coil-whiny" noise.

I can force the system to boot by entering GRUB and picking an older 4.x kernel.

I have nouveau disabled because it never worked with the 4.x kernel.

Thanks

```
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
menuentry 'Fedora (5.0.5-200.fc29.x86_64) 29 (Workstation Edition)' --class fedora --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --unrestricted $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.20.8-200.fc29.x86_64-advanced-f4720609-44ff-4b36-a4c4-31e8af02f468' {
    load_video
    set gfxpayload=keep
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  c60cd3be-dfeb-4a5f-983e-b2510b0b8991
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root c60cd3be-dfeb-4a5f-983e-b2510b0b8991
    fi
    linuxefi    /vmlinuz-5.0.5-200.fc29.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/fedora-root ro resume=/dev/mapper/fedora-swap rd.lvm.lv=fedora/root rd.luks.uuid=luks-0fcd4a94-b2b9-4613-8e04-780631a9f752 rd.lvm.lv=fedora/swap rhgb quiet nouveau.modeset=0 acpi_osi=Linux acpi_osi='!Windows 2015' LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
    initrdefi /initramfs-5.0.5-200.fc29.x86_64.img
}
menuentry 'Fedora (5.0.3-200.fc29.x86_64) 29 (Workstation Edition)' --class fedora --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --unrestricted $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.20.8-200.fc29.x86_64-advanced-f4720609-44ff-4b36-a4c4-31e8af02f468' {
    load_video
    set gfxpayload=keep
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  c60cd3be-dfeb-4a5f-983e-b2510b0b8991
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root c60cd3be-dfeb-4a5f-983e-b2510b0b8991
    fi
    linuxefi    /vmlinuz-5.0.3-200.fc29.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/fedora-root ro resume=/dev/mapper/fedora-swap rd.lvm.lv=fedora/root rd.luks.uuid=luks-0fcd4a94-b2b9-4613-8e04-780631a9f752 rd.lvm.lv=fedora/swap rhgb quiet nouveau.modeset=0 acpi_osi=Linux acpi_osi='!Windows 2015' LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
    initrdefi /initramfs-5.0.3-200.fc29.x86_64.img
}
menuentry 'Fedora (4.20.16-200.fc29.x86_64) 29 (Workstation Edition)' --class fedora --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --unrestricted $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.20.8-200.fc29.x86_64-advanced-f4720609-44ff-4b36-a4c4-31e8af02f468' {
    load_video
    set gfxpayload=keep
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  c60cd3be-dfeb-4a5f-983e-b2510b0b8991
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root c60cd3be-dfeb-4a5f-983e-b2510b0b8991
    fi
    linuxefi    /vmlinuz-4.20.16-200.fc29.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/fedora-root ro resume=/dev/mapper/fedora-swap rd.lvm.lv=fedora/root rd.luks.uuid=luks-0fcd4a94-b2b9-4613-8e04-780631a9f752 rd.lvm.lv=fedora/swap rhgb quiet nouveau.modeset=0 acpi_osi=Linux acpi_osi='!Windows 2015' LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
    initrdefi /initramfs-4.20.16-200.fc29.x86_64.img
}
```

Comment: Are you using NVIDIA's proprietary drivers, then?

Comment: All prior attempts to install the Nvidia driver have made the system unusable, so I am now only using Intel/CPU graphics and have the nouveau drivers disabled.

Comment: After reading through some forums, I have tried to boot the 5.x kernels without the nouveau override and without the rhgb flag, but nothing changed. Problem persists, only the older 4.x kernels work.

Comment: I have now installed nvidia drivers 3:418.56-1.fc29 but that changed nothing.
The laptop screen still flickers, accompanied by buzzing, "coil-whiny" sounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem has been discussed here:
https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/61964

It was introduced by an optimization for eDP 1.4+ ("link config fast and narrow") in the 5.x kernel; the patch doesn't work for some panels, including that of the XPS 15, and had to be rolled back.

The rollback was merged and should be released with the next kernel version (5.0.8):

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/21635d7311734d2d1b177f8a95e2f9386174b76d